# How to reduce the size of thumnails folder in Android?

Tags: storage, thumbnails

How can I reduce/get rid of the thumbnails folder in Android that is created under DCIM>Camera. I'm aware of the fact that thumbnails are auto-generated and will be generated again even if I delete them. But the point is my device has 6 GiB worth of the thumbnails folder, I keep almost no images or videos, still, it takes up a significant chunk, I know it is to optimize the loading of images in some apps, still 6 GiB in a device which has 32 GiB storage? And the worst thing is it keeps growing, never comes down. Is there a realistic way to bring down that 6 GiB to under 2 GiB. I'm ready to repeat this process every week or so if needed, I just need some space on my device.

Comment: Have you tried to delete all files in the thumbnail folder?

Comment: Yes, no help, the files go away for sometime but no space is freed

Comment: How do you know that those thumbnail files take up so much space? May be the app displaying the free/used space does not update the data after deleting or the files in that folder are not the one that use up the space. Make sure to check the current free space using an app like [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo).

Comment: Yes, I'm using diskinfo and file manager, they always show up 6 GiB for the thumnbails folder or 6.2 GiB for the whole DCIM folder as I only have 200 MB of photos, even those are pre-installed wallpapers. Another reason is, I have 24 GiB total, as 8 GiB is system reserved. I add space used by apps and other files and I get a maximum of 18, I basically get 18 GiB space in a 32 GiB phone because of this.

Comment: It does not matter how much flash your phone has. The only value that matters is the used and free values shown by [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) app for the `/data` partition. All the other partitions are of no concern to you. You still have not answered how you know that the thumbnails take so much space. My recommendation, use `adb shell` to access the file-system. That is the only way to get the real view of the file-system.

Comment: Here's the output of ```df -h command```  in the ADB shell. 
```/dev/block/dm-2          22G   16G  6.1G  73% /data```

It shows 16 GiB used, my apps are only 10 GiB, so clearly, 6 GiB thumbnails